# Debian Web hosting privilages/Apache attacks prevention and priv management

Tags: security, ssh, web-hosting

I'm wanting to setup a web hosting service similar to Dreamhost which allows SSH. I'm wanting to know how I can go about letting users connect via SSH but prevent any type of malicious activity. What methods should I go about in securing my Debian server against users who don't like to obey the rules, or don't wish to have restrictions (accessing root). Also how would I make sure some processes aren't running too long (x seconds then it will shut down the process).

I'm also wanting to host with Apache but I've had a few enemies not enjoy my presense on the internet and attack my server using apache exploits. What patches, modules or other secruity additions should I implement to prevent my apache server from taking my server down? I understand that without a hardware firewall, there are other requests that can take down my server, but I'm looking for things that can be done from a VPS on my end.

Finally, how do I allow users to host scripts that write in their home dirs so they can perform file read and write? I have managed to get the directories to have domain www dirs, but users face issues with writing.

Thanks!

Comment: You would probably get more productive answers if you asked each of your questions in a separate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [chroot](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/590) to limit ssh users to their home directories. If you will kill any long-time running process, you will periodicaly kill user shells :) Use `RCPULimit` for cgi scripts, and `max_execution_time` in php.ini for PHP. For securing apache see this [tips](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/misc/security_tips.html). If you think this is insufficient, use SELinux.

Comment: What if they wanted to install things like ffmpeg or if they decided to compile another binary, I don't want it executing for too long. Also, users can override `max_execution_time` :( Thanks for the help thus far though. I'll look into chroot more and I'll spend a long while reading the apache tips page!

Comment: OK, I'm your user. I had run [screen](http://www.gnu.org/s/screen/) with several shells: mc, text editor with unsaved file, ... I return on next day and see that all is broken! I want to compile some software with large sources, but compilation dyes every time! I become angry and leave your hosting. If you need to limit CPU time for all user's processes, use something like [cgroups](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/ch01.html). With PHP safemode enabled settings such as script timeouts cannot be overridden.

Comment: And if you want to allow users to do various things on server, not related to hosting web applications, like compiling/installing software, you better should suggest them VPS hosting.